# Endeca Experience Manager Performance increase

Tags: oracle, endeca, endeca-workbench

I want to increase the performance of Endeca Experience Manager by not throwing 504 error and increase in reboot process. Can some one please help me to diagnose the workbench.

Can removing the unused templates, help in increase the boot process of endeca.

And how can i validate while upload templates as which templates are missing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: And how can i validate while upload templates as which templates are missing. As there are any logs where can we verify

Comment: Which version of Endeca are you using? I've not seen templates having a direct impact on performance, but having unnecessary rules definitely does. Also in older versions of XM some of the completed projects don't automatically get cleaned up. That is why the version is important.

Comment: @radimpe 11.3.2

Comment: Ok. 11.3.2 does not have the old projects issue. Was fixed in a patch version of 11.3. When you registered XM as a service, did you increase the JVM memory sizes?

Comment: @radimpe   yes increased JVM memory sizes. Planning to remove unused rules (don't know how to do) and any other opinion you have would be helpful.

Comment: @radimpe : templates removal can help